# Touch screen panel + USB controller - send generic (x,y) data to PC

Tags: controller, touch, screen, panel

I'm wondering how impossible it can be to connect a touch panel (with USB controller) to a PC for it to send X,Y coordinates when an event happens (the panel is touched).

After searching the web I couldn't find more then pieces of information that don't tell the whole story.
Most of what I understood so far is that I can buy some touch panel development kit (ebay), create some basic C code that acts like a driver and then use those C functions to handle input on the device in other applications.

Question is, is the touch panel + USB controller + C code enough in order to use the input on the touch panel in other applications that I'll build myself (in C++ or other languages)? And what exactly would the C code be?
(I don't want to use the touch panel as a mouse, but independent. It only should provide coords when a touch event happend thru a function call - which would probably be part of the C code mentioned earlier)

An answer like "Buy this [touch panel] and [microcontroller], write this C code [code], compile it with g++, run the build and use the [getCoord()] function whenever the [touchHappened()] function returns true" would be too nice to be true?

A multi touch panel would be better (if not too expensive).
Also, all this on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if I am interpreting your question correctly but if all you are going for is that "When a user touches the screen give me the X and Y coordinates for that location on the screen to my application" you do not need a micro controller.

If you buy this [touch-filter](http://www.dx.com/p/7-inch-usb-touch-screen-film-makes-lcd-screens-touch-sensitive-12561#.U7Ec_7FgRjg) you can add it to any existing screen that you might intend your product for, it has a Linux driver too if you look around. You can also use basically any USB touch screen since most if not all will give you a mouse interface that you in turn can use to get the x, y coordinates. Not sure what language you are the most comfortable writing but this is how you do it with Python.

```
from Xlib import display
data = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()._data
data["root_x"], data["root_y"]
```